# Laravel on Docker on a Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, laravel, docker, docker-compose

## Description

I was followed this post
https://medium.com/@andrewmclagan/you-thought-laravel-homestead-was-easy-say-hello-to-docker-2c0639a0501

did everything until the end.

---

## Attempt

When running docker-compose up

I kept getting

```
  laravel  docker-compose up                                                                                                     
    Pulling cache (redis:latest)...                                                                                                   
    latest: Pulling from library/redis                                                                                                
    d13d02fa248d: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    a1846f364e39: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    dba901efed8c: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    b54b43b9d049: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    b5b9e2d5e9c6: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    7058d282fa00: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    Digest: sha256:07e7b6cb753f8d06a894e22af30f94e04844461ab6cb002c688841873e5e5116                                                   
    Status: Downloaded newer image for redis:latest                                                                                   
    Pulling database (mysql:latest)...                                                                                                
    latest: Pulling from library/mysql                                                                                                
    85b1f47fba49: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    27dc53f13a11: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    095c8ae4182d: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    0972f6b9a7de: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    1b199048e1da: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    159de3cf101e: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    2ff639f4e6d9: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    8c8d7a93157e: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    ce5afe5b139c: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    b8c916ff94d5: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    e934932d4d25: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    Digest: sha256:eb9a3bca059ee178b5a69a2443462d156ff5b3d3f739c516b62d9d902ba49132                                                   
    Status: Downloaded newer image for mysql:latest                                                                                   
    Pulling web (andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm:latest)...
    latest: Pulling from andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm                                                                                     
    6d827a3ef358: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    f8f2e0556751: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    5c9972dca3fd: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    451b9524cb06: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    c1357c61de85: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    9c51a5960e41: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    c2eece0451f8: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    9a49cb564871: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    edb490880878: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    b2779904d8fe: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    b9dfc6b1efda: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    0ecdfed17608: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    8e6eeda8f4a2: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    75459004e16b: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    6c8b0e24af3a: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    Digest: sha256:8a130c1e090fe5e9b6bc3785434362e85e6b02de4bb57378f7a05f3f9eef430a                                                   
    Status: Downloaded newer image for andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm:latest                                                                
    Pulling load_balancer (tutum/haproxy:latest)...
    latest: Pulling from tutum/haproxy                                                                                                
    6c953ac5d795: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    3eed5ff20a90: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    f8419ea7c1b5: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    51900bc9e720: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    4044952661ee: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    453310b4b2df: Pull complete                                                                                                       
    Digest: sha256:31e8a98d4255298d285499635e8ed90fd37bacf4e5901899cee2d153d9875aae                                                   
    Status: Downloaded newer image for tutum/haproxy:latest                                                                           
    Creating laravel_database_1 ... 
    Creating laravel_cache_1 ... 
    Creating laravel_cache_1
    Creating laravel_database_1 ... done                                                                                              
    Creating laravel_web_1 ... 
    Creating laravel_web_1 ... done                                                                                                   
    Creating laravel_load_balancer_1 ... 
    Creating laravel_load_balancer_1 ... error                                                                                        

    ERROR: for laravel_load_balancer_1  Cannot start service load_balancer: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint laravel_load_balancer_1 (a81a648c298756eae2d892fc6666c2ecd8ed9226532b9a03fe668431b417c353): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE)

    ERROR: for load_balancer  Cannot start service load_balancer: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint laravel_load_balancer_1 (a81a648c298756eae2d892fc6666c2ecd8ed9226532b9a03fe668431b417c353): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE)
    ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

---

According to this link :
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3277#issuecomment-232505775

I tried to list

**laravel  lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN**

```
SpotifyWebHelpe   579 bheng    5u     IPv4 0x57408b419711d73d        0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:4370 (LISTEN)                          
SpotifyWebHelpe   579 bheng    6u     IPv4 0x57408b41988d792d        0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:4380 (LISTEN)                          
Adobe\x20Deskto   645 bheng   10u     IPv4 0x57408b41993d473d        0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:15292 (LISTEN)                         
plugin_host     15031 bheng   33u     IPv4 0x57408b41867dd415        0t0     TCP *:35729 (LISTEN)                                 
node            64677 bheng   29u     IPv4 0x57408b41b05f1415        0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:63509 (LISTEN)                         
node            64677 bheng   30u     IPv4 0x57408b41b08e7225        0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:44529 (LISTEN)                         
node            64677 bheng   46u     IPv4 0x57408b41b1f66225        0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:59596 (LISTEN)                         
node            68369 bheng   13u     IPv6 0x57408b41a8f82fcd        0t0     TCP *:3001 (LISTEN)                                  
node            68369 bheng   16u     IPv6 0x57408b41a8f8350d        0t0     TCP *:4000 (LISTEN)                                  
node            68373 bheng   13u     IPv6 0x57408b418a378a8d        0t0     TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)                                  
vpnkit          75362 bheng   21u     IPv4 0x57408b41b0c1cb1d        0t0     TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)                                  
vpnkit          75362 bheng   22u     IPv6 0x57408b41a5c0ffcd        0t0     TCP [::1]:8000 (LISTEN)                              
vpnkit          75362 bheng   34u     IPv4 0x57408b41876b7225        0t0     TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)                                  
vpnkit          75362 bheng   37u     IPv6 0x57408b4186914a8d        0t0     TCP [::1]:8080 (LISTEN)                              
postgres        75544 bheng    5u     IPv6 0x57408b41897e250d        0t0     TCP [::1]:5432 (LISTEN)                              
postgres        75544 bheng    6u     IPv4 0x57408b41969b0035        0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:5432 (LISTEN)                          
Dropbox         77901 bheng  129u     IPv6 0x57408b41a8f82a8d        0t0     TCP *:17500 (LISTEN)                                 
Dropbox         77901 bheng  130u     IPv4 0x57408b41876b8415        0t0     TCP *:17500 (LISTEN)                                 
Dropbox         77901 bheng  166u     IPv4 0x57408b41aec8f035        0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:17600 (LISTEN)                         
Dropbox         77901 bheng  171u     IPv4 0x57408b41a83de73d        0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:17603 (LISTEN)                         
VBoxHeadless    82156 bheng   16u     IPv4 0x57408b41afdb792d        0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:57771 (LISTEN)
```

I don't really `com.docker.slirp` or anything with `0.0.0.0:80`
that lead to

> unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE)

---

## Output of docker ps

**laravel  docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                NAMES                                                             
00326cc3f107        andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm      "/usr/bin/supervisord"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         80/tcp, 443/tcp                                      laravel_web_9                                                     
5960766c60d3        andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm      "/usr/bin/supervisord"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         80/tcp, 443/tcp                                      laravel_web_4                                                     
7e3fbb336429        andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm      "/usr/bin/supervisord"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         80/tcp, 443/tcp                                      laravel_web_8                                                     
b7afdef8dd9d        andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm      "/usr/bin/supervisord"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         80/tcp, 443/tcp                                      laravel_web_6                                                     
9b0bb457e6bd        andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm      "/usr/bin/supervisord"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         80/tcp, 443/tcp                                      laravel_web_7                                                     
0f16bc26e8c0        andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm      "/usr/bin/supervisord"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         80/tcp, 443/tcp                                      laravel_web_5                                                     
fa0eed3a648d        andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm      "/usr/bin/supervisord"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         80/tcp, 443/tcp                                      laravel_web_10                                                    
72076290a808        andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm      "/usr/bin/supervisord"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         80/tcp, 443/tcp                                      laravel_web_2                                                     
d829a066a0bf        andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm      "/usr/bin/supervisord"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         80/tcp, 443/tcp                                      laravel_web_3                                                     
d64a6b623460        andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm      "/usr/bin/supervisord"   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         80/tcp, 443/tcp                                      laravel_web_1                                                     
b52d1136c07f        mysql                         "docker-entrypoint..."   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         3306/tcp                                             laravel_database_1
fa3483793731        redis                         "docker-entrypoint..."   12 hours ago        Up 12 hours         6379/tcp                                             laravel_cache_1
f3d2d2377951        sscportalapi_ssc-portal-api   "sh -c 'npm instal..."   22 hours ago        Up 22 hours         80/tcp, 443/tcp, 43554/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   sscportalapi_ssc-portal-api_1
19fc6aeb600d        sscportaladmin_admin-portal   "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   39 hours ago        Up 39 hours         0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                                 sscportaladmin_admin-portal_1
```

I'm on a Mac and I don't know much about Docker. What else should I check on my Mac ?

Comment: Looks like others have been having the same issue - a suggested workaround https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3277#issuecomment-232505775

Comment: Can you add the output of `docker ps`? It sounds like another container is already running that has port 80 published.

Comment: Ok I will add it.